# How does Windows 2012 choose it's network filter settings of Internet vs DataCenter as seen in netstat -y

Tags: windows, rss, windows-server-2012

I am working on pushing large amounts of data over SMB 3.0 and when I sometimes connect two Windows 2012 servers together sometimes they connect using the Internet Profile and sometimes using the DataCenter profile when I check using netstat -y.

The Internet profile transfers are slower because they use both ECN disables and Congestion provider to CTCP instead of DCTCP.  When I force the subnet to use the Data Center profile by adding it using Set-NETTCPSetting, the transfer is faster.  Does anyone know how Microsoft is choosing where an IP address should use the Internet Profile instead of the DataCenter profile

[image: Sample picture from the Internet]

```
>Powershell: Get-NetTCPSetting
SettingName                     : Internet
MinRto(ms)                      : 300
InitialCongestionWindow(MSS)    : 4
CongestionProvider              : CTCP
CwndRestart                     : False
DelayedAckTimeout(ms)           : 50
DelayedAckFrequency             : 2
MemoryPressureProtection        : Disabled
AutoTuningLevelLocal            : Normal
AutoTuningLevelGroupPolicy      : NotConfigured
AutoTuningLevelEffective        : Local
EcnCapability                   : Disabled
Timestamps                      : Disabled
InitialRto(ms)                  : 3000
ScalingHeuristics               : Disabled
DynamicPortRangeStartPort       : 49152
DynamicPortRangeNumberOfPorts   : 16384
AutomaticUseCustom              : Disabled
NonSackRttResiliency            : Disabled
ForceWS                         : Disabled
MaxSynRetransmissions           : 2
AutoReusePortRangeStartPort     : 0
AutoReusePortRangeNumberOfPorts : 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen any documentation for the logic behind Automatic Settings Profile selection, but you can override that logic with your own by using a Transport Filter.  The default Filter sets all connections to Automatic.

```
PS C:\> Get-NetTransportFilter

SettingName       : Automatic
Protocol          : TCP
LocalPortStart    : 0
LocalPortEnd      : 65535
RemotePortStart   : 0
RemotePortEnd     : 65535
DestinationPrefix : *
```

You can override that for specific connections with the [New-NetTransportFilter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/%5Clibrary/hh826120(v=wps.630).aspx) cmdlet.

You can use something like

```
New-NetTransportFilter -SettingName Datacenter -DestinationPrefix 192.168.0.0/24
```

Or

```
New-NetTransportFilter -SettingName DataCenter -LocalPortStart 0 -LocalPortEnd 65536 -RemotePortStart 1433 -RemotePortEnd 1433
```